# WPF ListView Binding issues with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListView` which binds to an `ObservableCollection` named `GunsCollection`

```xml
<Grid>
<ListView x:Name="lstView" Height="300" ItemsSource="{Binding GunsCollection}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Gun Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ModelName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UnitCost}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

When I create the instance of `GunsCollection` in the constructor of `MainWindow`, my ListView doesn't show anything and is empty.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Gun> GunsCollection { get; set; } 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        var GunsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Gun>() // doesn't work!
        {
            new Gun() {ModelName = "AK-47", UnitCost = 2700 },
            new Gun() {ModelName = "M4A4", UnitCost = 3100 },
        };
    }
}
```

But when I create the instance of `GunsCollection` on the same line with its declaration, the `ListView` works and shows all of the items contained.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Gun> GunsCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Gun>(); 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        GunsCollection.Add(new Gun() { ModelName = "AK-47", UnitCost = 2700 });
        GunsCollection.Add(new Gun() { ModelName = "M4A4", UnitCost = 3100 });
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Remove `var` in your first example (looks like a typo), and move the line setting set the `DataContext` AFTER setting `GunsCollection` then it should work. Your `GunsCollection` property setter doesn’t raise a `PropertyChanged` event and therefore order matters. Your second example works because `Add()` DOES raise a `CollectionChangedEvent` (triggers binding update), that is what “observable” means when using `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: I didn't see the `var` in the first place (And yes it was a mistake on my part). I did implement INotifyPropertyChanged in my view class but raising the `PropertyChanged` event in the property setter of `ObservableCollection`  is something I have never heard of. I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Whether or not to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and binding to `ObservableCollection<T>` vs a vanilla collection type like `List<T>` are separate concerns. Do the first is when you want the setting of a property trigger binding update and the second when you want binding to update upon changing items in the collection (has nothing to do w/the the collection property itself changing due to setting it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example you display, you create a new local variable and don't assign it to your public collection which is bound to your view.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Gun> GunsCollection { get; set; } 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        GunsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Gun>() 
        {
            new Gun() {ModelName = "AK-47", UnitCost = 2700 },
            new Gun() {ModelName = "M4A4", UnitCost = 3100 },
        };
    }
}
```

Remove `var`

Comment: Now that I noticed this silly mistake, I wish I could bury my head in the sand.. thanks for pointing out my mistake

Comment: @ZhenHao No worries, enjoy making your CS related app

Answer (score 0):

In your first example the *GunsCollection* you fill with data will no longer exist after the constructor has been executed. You've created a new variable which has nothing to do with your class property (even if it has the same name).